# How do I use requests_cache with django?

Tags: django, caching, python-requests

I am currently using requests to receive json data from third party API services and would like to cache the data to limit the number of call requests.
If my requests code are inside methods in views.py, where do I put the install_cache code below? When should this line be called?

requests_cache.install_cache('demo_cache')

Answer (score 1):

You can just put that line at the top of your `views.py` module.

If possible, though, the best way to use requests-cache is with [CachedSession](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/general.html#sessions), which is a drop-in replacement for [requests.Session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects). This is preferable over `install_cache()` for [reasons explained here](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/general.html#patching-limitations-potential-issues).

```py
from requests_cache import CachedSession

session = CachedSession()
response = session.get('http://some_url.com')
```

Any requests made from that session object will be cached, and if needed you can make non-cached requests using a regular `requests.Session` or `requests.get()`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

First, here you can find all information about cache in django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/

Second:

If you need to cache the query result, you can use the dafault cache system or another cache framework (see first point).

For the dafault cache system you need to import the cache first, set the value and get it when needed. (put the code in your views.py)

Import cache

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

Set value from API. The dafult value is:

```
cache.set(name, your queryset, expirytime in second)
```

To evaluated the value use:

```
cache.get(name)
```

Now just create a check if the cache exist or not.

Hope this help

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about `requests_cache` at all.